# How to add an icon to my xaml 2017 VS programme

Tags: xaml, uwp-xaml

I want to add an icon to my button.

```
 <Button Name="btnPlay"
         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
         Content="Play"
         Margin="10"
         VerticalAlignment="Top"
         Click="btnPlay_Click">
    <Button.Icon>
      <Image Source="play icon.png" />
    </Button.Icon>
</Button>
```

This is my current code but it does not seem to be working. Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Are you sure that's your current code? I went to edit it thinking that some of it was just not displaying, but no sure enough it's pretty broken syntax. It should just be `<Button><StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"><Image .../><TextBlock Text="Play"/></StackPanel></Button>`

Comment: This is it. <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"  <Grid.RowDefinitions> <RowDefinition Height="*" />
  <RowDefinition Height="40" /> </Grid.RowDefinitions> <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <StackPanel>
  <Button Name="btnPlay" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Play"
                   
      Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="btnPlay_Click"><Button.Icon>
                    <Image Source="play icon.png" /> </Button.Icon> </Button>

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Button.Icon` as a thing. You can do something like [SymbolIcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/icons) but in the same way as documentation shows. Another issue you'll likely run into is with your file (spaces in it) name, its relative path, and whether you have it marked as a resource etc. I'd start there.

Answer (score 0):

The [Button](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.button#properties) control has no `Icon` property in UWP. If you want to show image in Button's content, you could custom its content like the following:

```
<Button Name="btnPlay"
     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
     Margin="10"
     VerticalAlignment="Top"
     Click="BtnPlay_Click">
        <Button.Content>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="/Assets/play.png"  Width="30" Height="20"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Play"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

[image]